# How to sort artboards by artboard order in the layer list in sketch?

Tags: layers, sketch-app, artboard

Is there a way to sort artboards in Sketch **from left to right** according to their order in the layer list?

What I mean is doing it *without* changing the artboard names or reordering them in the layer list, only to reflect the list order to sort the artboards from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I’ve got the solution. It’s a feature of the *Auto Layout* plugin called *Arrange in Grid*: https://animaapp.github.io/docs/v1/guide/09-arrange.html and the plugin can be installed through Sketch Toolbox or https://animaapp.github.io/Auto-Layout/

You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sort Me plugin to sort your Artboard.

https://github.com/romashamin/sort-me-sketch

Sort Me is a Sketch plugin. Select artboards or layers and use:

<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to sort them this way:

- Layer 3
- Layer 2
- Layer 1

<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to sort opposite:

- Layer 1
- Layer 2
- Layer 3